# Activity needs 2 themes to use 2 libraries (each needs to set a theme)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app that uses 2 libraries, each of which needs to set a theme in the activity to function properly. The 2 libraries are ActionBarSherlock and the ViewPageIndicator library.

I can not set 2 themes in the activity manifest, so I tried combining the 2 themes into one but encountered problems (not sure if this is even possible).

Just wondering if anyone has a solution to this issue? Thanks.

Comment: where did u see "each of which needs to set a theme in the activity to function properly" ? ,

Comment: ActionBarSherlock needs a theme and ViewPageIndicator needs a theme for tab indicator, it may not need a theme for most of the indicators but for some it does (it gets its styles from the context)

Answer (score 0):

The ViewPagerIndicator does not *need* to set a theme, you can use one (modifying a Sherlock theme to personalize the indicators is definitely possible) but it is not compulsory, you can also set personalize your pager indicators via methods in your code, or in each individual xml layout. 
Have a look at the example implementation on the [github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). If you want to use the styles in xml for both , [this part of the sample project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml) shows how to set the styles for the indicators, just combine that with the style you use for ActionBarSherlock.